# How can I create an object with input values and push it to array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have the following array in React:

```
const employees=[
    {
      id:1,
      firstName:'John',
      lastName:'Martinez'
    },
    {
        id:2,
        firstName:'Julio',
        lastName:'Mariella'
    }
]
```

I want to generate an array from user's input. For example user types their first name and last name in certain input fields and then these values are inserted into array and pushed to the employees object.

I tried to insert array with:

```
employees.push(employee);
```

but that's not correct.

Comment: How is React involved here?  If you just want to add a value to an array, the code you have does exactly that.  But the use of the `reactjs` tag implies that you're trying to do something else, such as perhaps update state in a React component.  Can you clarify the problem and provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Please show your attempt. `employees.push(employee);` is in the right direction but were not sure how you're creating `employee`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react then you should use state hook like this:

> replace the initial array value with your initial array

```
const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([]);
```

> add the new employee

```
setEmployees(prevEmployees => ([...prevEmployees, ...newEmployee]));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it, I have added an input for you to enter info and add to array. This is not react, just an example of the code you provided to work, the way you could try in react is underneath code (not tested)

```js
const employees=[
        {
          id:1,
          firstName:'John',
          lastName:'Martinez'
        },
        {
            id:2,
            firstName:'Julio',
            lastName:'Mariella'
        }
    ]
    
function add() {    
var new_name = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
var new_lastname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;   

if (new_name === '') { alert("Fill in Name"); return; }
if (new_lastname === '') { alert("Fill in Last Name"); return; }


var last = employees.slice(-1)[0]       // Get last array //
var newid = last.id;                    // Gets last ID in array //


newid++;                                // Adds 1 to the new ID //

const newID = {                         // Make new Data //
    id:newid, 
    firstname:new_name, 
    lastname:new_lastname
    };

employees.push(newID);                  // Add to array //
console.log(employees);
alert(new_name+' '+new_lastname+" added");
    }
```

```html
First Name : <input type='text' name="firstname" id='firstname' /><BR>
Last Name : <input type='text' name="lastname" id='lastname' /><BR>
<button onclick="add()">ADD</button>
```

This is sort of how you would do it in react, I have not added the function for input or id increment but should work.

```
const [ employees, setEmployees ] = useState(
        [
        {
          id:1,
          firstName:'John',
          lastName:'Martinez'
        },
        {
            id:2,
            firstName:'Julio',
            lastName:'Mariella'
        }
    ]
)


const [ newEmployee, setNewEmployee ] = useState(
        [
        {
          id:3,
          firstName:'David',
          lastName:'Jones'
        }
    ]
)


// In a function //

    setEmployees(employees => [...employees, newEmployee]);

//
```